# random number generation and two DO....END loops in sas

Tags: random, sas

I need to Use SAS random number generation functions `RAND()` and  a `DO....END loop` to create 100 obs in variable named X then I want to use another DO loop of 500 rounds to generate a total of 500 samples, each with 100 obs.  a sample is basically sampling from a standard normal distribution.

I tried the following code but it does not give me what I need:

```
data A;
call streaminit(123);   /* set random number seed */
do i = 1 to 100;
X = rand("Normal");     /* random number generator */
 output;
end;

do r = 1 to 500 ;
if i then X = rand("Normal");
output;
end;
run;
```

Any input will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Sounds like you want to nest one do loop inside of the other.

Comment: Do you want 500 rows of 100 variables (`x1` to `x100`) or 50,000 rows of `round#`, `sample#`, `X` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a data step solution

```
data want;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
  do I=1 to 500;                                                                                                                     
    do _iorc_=1 to 100;                                                                                                                 
      X=rand ("normal");                                                                                                             
      output;                                                                                                                          
    end;                                                                                                                               
  end;                                                                                                                                 
run;
```

Comment: Thanks  a lot. But what is the meanining of `_iorc_`

Comment: Sure thing. _IORC_ is just an automatic variable that is automatically dropped. I could also have used i instead of _iorc_, but then I would have to drop it again.

Answer (score 2):

Perfect time to use PROC IML:

```
proc iml;
call streaminit(123); /* set seed */
x = j(500, 100); /* allocate 500 by 100 matrix */
call randgen(x, "Normal"); /* fill matrix with N(0,1) random draws */

create mydata from x; /* move matrix to a dataset in the work directory */
append from x;
close mydata;
quit;
```